# Which takes less space as a in mongodb - an empty string or a boolean?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, meteor

I have to store User IDs as "keys" for an object in a mongodb document. I have two options:

1. To use empty string as the value:
   Sample object:

```
    "followers" : {
        "HIdandiwiAJimw" : "",
        "NJDwbajbmBWjun" : ""
    }
```

2. To use boolean true as the value:

```
    "followers" : {
        "HIdandiwiAJimw" : true,
        "NJDwbajbmBWjun" : true
    }
```

Which of these would have less memory impact? If I can use something better than this, I would like to know about it.

MongoDB Version: 4.0.2 ,
NodeJS Version: 8.11.4 - x64    (If it matters)

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59/when-to-use-null-and-when-to-use-an-empty-string If memory usage is that important to you, you should probably not use mongoDB ;)

Comment: It looks like you are storing values (User IDs) as keys. If the empty string or `true` value for a User ID is irrelevant, an array of unique follower IDs would make more sense. As a general pattern I would be wary of adding data with potentially unbounded growth into a single document: large documents will become performance outliers and could eventually reach the 16MB document cap. The MongoDB Labs [Socialite](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/socialite) project has some examples of scalable design that are worth reviewing (in particular, see the User Graph Service for your use case).